# Use MongoDB $near within $and

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to search "Places", which are near to a Location AND meet some other criteria as seen here:

```
var places = Places.find(
{
    $and :
    [
        { categories : placesCategory },

        {
            $or :
            [
                { name    : { $regex : searchQuery, $options : 'i' } },
                { city    : { $regex : searchQuery, $options : 'i' } },
                { country : { $regex : searchQuery, $options : 'i' } }
            ]
        },

        {
            location :
            {
                $near : [ nearLng, nearLat ],
                $maxDistance : 67.15 // radians
            }
        }
    ]
}).fetch();
```

However the console tells me that "$near can't be inside another $ operator".

Is there a way to include the $near inside the $and?

Or what would be the best practice?

Comment: That's not the problem. Like I said the console is saying "$near can't be inside another $ operator"

Comment: take a look on [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#pipe._S_geoNear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include your $near query inside your $and statement. You can place it outside and it will stil work.

```
var places = Places.find(
{
    location :
    {
        $near : [ nearLng, nearLat ],
        $maxDistance : 67.15 // radians
    },
    $and :
    [
        { categories : placesCategory },

        {
            $or :
            [
                { name    : { $regex : searchQuery, $options : 'i' } },
                { city    : { $regex : searchQuery, $options : 'i' } },
                { country : { $regex : searchQuery, $options : 'i' } }
            ]
        }
    ]
}).fetch();
```

I am however not sure if your $near query is working properly. I prefer a more specific query with an in '2dsphere' on the coordinates. For example:

```
location:
{
    $near:
    {
        $geometry:
        {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [ nearLng, nearLat ]
        },
        $maxDistance: 67.15 // radians
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: In order to use the above query, make sure you are saving you data according to this model:

```
location: {
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: 'Point',
        default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        default: [0,0],
        index: '2dsphere'
    }
}
```

When you want to find places inside a rectangle, you wil probably need the *$box* operator. This is an example search query (*please note*, I have no experience with it. You might need to change your model and/or add an index to improve the query):

```
location: {
     $geoWithin: {
        $box: [
          [ <bottom left coordinates> ],
          [ <upper right coordinates> ]
        ]
     }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: You just saved me about 70 lines of code. Thanks!
I also tried the second suggestion, however the $geometry operator is not recognised. I think it only needs some minor modification.
I will also try to implement something like an "inside bounds". Do you have something on your mind, how I could find Locations inside a rectangle / inside bounds?

Comment: No problem! I have updated my answer. The second query probably does not work because your model is "wrong", I have included my way of storing the data. I have also added an example to search inside a rectangle but I have no experience with that to be honest. Good luck!

Comment: Worked like a charm! I will be using both solutions. Thanks!