# How can I insert loc coordinates in [-XXX.XXXXXXX, XX.XXXXXX] format?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am new to meteor-Js and simple schema. I am practicing Mongo Zips db. I have following schema:

```
    Schemas.Zips  = new SimpleSchema({


    _id:{
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },    
    city:{
        type: String,
        label : 'City',
        autoform:{
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "text",
                autocomplete:'off'
            }
        }    
    },
    loc:{
        type: Object            
     },    
    'loc.latitude':{
        type: Number,
        label : 'Lati',
        autoform:{
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "text",
                autocomplete:'off'
            }
        }
    },
    'loc.longitude':{
        type: Number,
        label : 'Longi',
        autoform:{
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "text",
                autocomplete:'off'
            }
        }
    },    
    pop:{
        type: Number,
        label : 'Population',
        autoform:{
            afFieldInput: {
                    type: "text",
                    autocomplete:'off'
            }
        }
     },    
     state:{
        type: String,
        label : 'State',
        autoform:{
            afFieldInput: {
            type: "text",
            autocomplete:'off'
            }
        }
     }    
});  

Collections.Zips.attachSchema(Schemas.Zips);
```

How can I insert loc coordinates in [-XXX.XXXXXXX, XX.XXXXXX] format in mongodb using simpleschema.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127240/use-mongodb-near-within-and) question

Comment: Set decimal to true (https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/blob/master/README.md#decimal)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to set the loc.latitude and loc.longitude both with [decimal set to true](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#decimal) to allow non integer values.

Or if you're using autoform as well you could take a look at [yogiben:autoform-maps](https://atmospherejs.com/yogiben/autoform-map)

```
loc:{
    type: Object            
 },    
'loc.latitude':{
    type: Number,
    decimal:true,
    label : 'Lati',
    autoform:{
        afFieldInput: {
            type: "text",
            autocomplete:'off'
        }
    }
},
'loc.longitude':{
    type: Number,
    decimal:true,
    label : 'Longi',
    autoform:{
        afFieldInput: {
            type: "text",
            autocomplete:'off'
        }
    }
}
```